# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS lost internet connectoin out of sudden

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, internet, ipv6, ipv4

My PC is connected to a router. The router has been working all the time and had internet connection. Several days ago I noticed that I suddenly cannot connect to my PC through the router admin page anymore. I don't understand whether it was my pc's configurations fault or NetworkManager fault or whatsoever. Many thanks to any hints!

`syslog` of that day:

```
Jun 24 04:06:32 myPC001 NetworkManager[724]: <error> [1687572392.0562] dhcp4 (enp1s0): error -111 dispatching events
Jun 24 04:06:32 myPC001 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1687572392.0562] dhcp4 (enp1s0): state changed extended -> fail
Jun 24 04:06:32 myPC001 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1687572392.0563] device (enp1s0): DHCPv4: trying to acquire a new lease within 90 seconds
Jun 24 04:06:55 myPC001 ntpd[419423]: error resolving pool ntp.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
Jun 24 04:06:55 myPC001 ntpd[419423]: Soliciting pool server 0.0.0.1
Jun 24 04:07:24 myPC001 ntpd[419423]: Soliciting pool server 0.0.0.0
Jun 24 04:07:59 myPC001 ntpd[419423]: error resolving pool ntp.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
Jun 24 04:07:59 myPC001 ntpd[419423]: Soliciting pool server 0.0.0.1
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1687572482.5143] device (enp1s0): DHCPv4: grace period expired
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1687572482.5144] device (enp1s0): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1687572482.5214] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 NetworkManager[724]: <warn>  [1687572482.5291] device (enp1s0): Activation: failed for connection 'netplan-enp1s0'
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 dbus-daemon[723]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.10' (uid=0 pid=724 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1687572482.5503] device (enp1s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 avahi-daemon[1212771]: Withdrawing address record for fe81::76fe:49ff:fe7b:6101 on enp1s0.
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 avahi-daemon[1212771]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp1s0.IPv6 with address fe81::76fe:49ff:fe7b:6101.
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 avahi-daemon[1212771]: Interface enp1s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1687572482.5756] dhcp4 (enp1s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1687572482.5760] dhcp4 (enp1s0): state changed fail -> done
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 dbus-daemon[723]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 avahi-daemon[1212771]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.101 on enp1s0.
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 avahi-daemon[1212771]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp1s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.101.
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 avahi-daemon[1212771]: Interface enp1s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 whoopsie[934]: [04:08:02] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 nm-dispatcher[1572748]: run-parts: failed to stat component /etc/network/if-post-down.d/avahi-daemon: No such file or directory
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1687572482.6495] policy: auto-activating connection 'netplan-enp1s0' (cac41fbe-bc18-3d87-bba7-af2af7f8ffab)
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1687572482.6636] device (enp1s0): Activation: starting connection 'netplan-enp1s0' (cac41fbe-bc18-3d87-bba7-af2af7f8ffab)
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1687572482.6669] device (enp1s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1687572482.6706] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1687572482.6733] device (enp1s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1687572482.6874] device (enp1s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1687572482.6896] dhcp4 (enp1s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 avahi-daemon[1212771]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp1s0.IPv6 with address fe81::76fe:49ff:fe7b:6101.
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 avahi-daemon[1212771]: New relevant interface enp1s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1015]: dbus-daemon[1015]: [session uid=125 pid=1015] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.10' (uid=125 pid=1300 comm="/usr/libexec/gsd-sharing " label="unconfined")
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 avahi-daemon[1212771]: Registering new address record for fe81::76fe:49ff:fe7b:6101 on enp1s0.*.
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1015]: dbus-daemon[1015]: [session uid=125 pid=1015] Activating service name='ca.desrt.dconf' requested by ':1.2' (uid=125 pid=1061 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1015]: dbus-daemon[1015]: [session uid=125 pid=1015] Successfully activated service 'ca.desrt.dconf'
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1015]: dbus-daemon[1015]: [session uid=125 pid=1015] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 gsd-sharing[1300]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 gsd-sharing[1300]: message repeated 3 times: [ Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1]
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 internet.sh[1533537]: [sudo] password for myPC:
Jun 24 04:08:02 myPC001 internet.sh[1572761]: ping: connect: Network is unreachable
Jun 24 04:08:03 myPC001 ovpn-client[2165992]: write UDP: Network is unreachable (code=101)
Jun 24 04:08:05 myPC001 ntpd[419423]: Deleting interface #25 enp1s0, 192.168.1.101#123, interface stats: received=890, sent=4015, dropped=0, active_time=199980 secs
```

Here is output from `nmcli connection show netplan-enp1s0 | grep -e fail -e method`

```
ipv4.method:                            auto
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv6.method:                            auto
ipv6.may-fail:                          yes
proxy.method:                           none
```

Comment: If you're actually running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, I'd hope you keep your system offline as you're years behind on applying security fixes to your system.  A fully upgraded 20.04 system will report itself as 20.04.6 (see https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/ though that date is the ISO release, installed systems upgraded in the week before that date!) with your details as provided implying you've not applied security fixes since early-mid 2021.